# Function in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, random

this is my code:

```
import random

a = 10000
b = random.random()
c = 2

def random1(a,b,c):
    z = a * b * c
    print(z)

def random2():
    for i in range(10):
        random1(a,b,c)

random2()
```

I have a problem with my output, because function random2() gives me ten exactly the same numbers, for example:

```
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
10652.014111193188
```

Where is the mistake? Or I can't use function that gives me random numbers in a for loop :/. Everything is fine, when I'm looping formula instead of function, the problem shows only when function is in for loop.

Comment: There is nothing random in `random1` or `random2`. The only RNG call here is `b = random.random()`, which gets **one random number** and assigns it to `b`. It doesn't make `b` shorthand for "call `random.random`.

Comment: Or in other words, "I rolled a die once and looked at it 10 times, and I saw the same number every time! What gives?"

Comment: try `b = random.random` and then call it `random1(a,b(),c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple change should do it, bind `b` to `random.random`, and then call `b()` while passing to `random1`

```
import random

a = 10000
b = random.random
c = 2

def random1(a,b,c):
    z = a * b * c
    print(z)

def random2():
    for i in range(10):
        # call b() here instead of b
        random1(a,b(),c)

random2()
```

Comment: Great, this works for me. Small change changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

`b` never changes, even though you initialized it with a random value.  Neither `a` nor `c` ever changes, either, but you probably expected that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldn't be putting b into the random functions at all! If you want the function Random1 to create a random number multiplied by a and c:

import random

```
a = 10000
# remarked: b = random.random()  
c = 2

def random1(a,c):
    b = random.random()
    z = a * b * c
    print(z)



def random2(): # I would call it testRandom1
    for i in range(10):
        random1(a ,c)

random2() # test random1 ten times.
```